# Woocommerce cropping not working as it should?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried just about everything I can find on the internet. Here are my current woocommerce cropping settings:

[image: Woocommerce settings]

The problem is, after I re-generate the images and I go back to this page, I end up with this:

[image: Woocommerce settings sadness]

Why would it do this and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

In fact, it doesn't reset the hard crop settings after I regenerate the images. It simply saves it as "hard crop" checked after I uncheck them, even though it initially shows that I've changed it?

**UPDATE 2**

It seems to be related to [this](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203036386-Woocommerce-hard-crop-option-not-saving).

**UPDATE 3**

I tried adding this:

```
add_action( 'aftersetup_theme', function () {

    // Add image sizes
    $shop_thumbnail = wc_get_image_size( 'shop_thumbnail' );
    $shop_catalog   = wc_get_image_size( 'shop_catalog' );
    $shop_single    = wc_get_image_size( 'shop_single' );

    // In the lines below, true = hard crop; false = proportional
    $shop_thumbnail['crop'] = false;
    $shop_catalog['crop'] = false;
    $shop_single['crop'] = false;

    add_image_size( 'shop_thumbnail', $shop_thumbnail['width'], $shop_thumbnail['height'], $shop_thumbnail['crop'] );
    add_image_size( 'shop_catalog', $shop_catalog['width'], $shop_catalog['height'], $shop_catalog['crop'] );
    add_image_size( 'shop_single', $shop_single['width'], $shop_single['height'], $shop_single['crop'] );
}, 20 );
```

And then I re-generated the images, and still no luck?

**UPDATE 4:**

The site can be viewed here:

```
http://www.diamondcouturelondon.co.uk/
```

**UPDATE 5:**

The plugins installed include:

- Contact Form 7
- Lollum Framework
- oAuth Twitter Feed for Developers
- Regenerate Thumbnails
- Revolution Slider
- WooCommerce
- YITH WooCommerce Wishlist

**UPDATE 6:**

I disabled ALL the plugins except for WooCommerce. I then went to this page:

```
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=products
```

There I again unchecked "hard crop" next to all items. I pressed save. Upon reload, the items are unchecked, but if I refresh the page, they are checked. So the changes weren't saved. In other words, WITH ONLY WOOCOMMERCE enabled, it STILL doesn't save my hard crop settings.

That leaves me with only one other possible external influence --> the theme. But I can't see how that can be affecting it.

Comment: Have you got any plugins? On the link you posted some reported the issue to be cause by a plugin conflict too which could be why the fix on that post did not work for you.

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary, but I will update my post to include that too.

Comment: Have you tried de-activating the other plugins and trying it? That'll at least let you know if there's a plugin conflict...

Comment: I'm going to try that quickly.

Comment: Please see my updated in my question. It made no difference whatsoever. I guess  I need to ask the theme author.

Comment: You have something overwriting theses options_name : `shop_catalog_image_size` / `shop_single_image_size` / `shop_thumbnail_image_size`. You should try to search them on your theme

Comment: What version of WooCommerce are you using? I cannot reproduce this. Also image settings should be at `admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=products&section=display` Agree with @XcID that your theme might be overriding those settings as it might think it is better suited to a non-cropped look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_shop_thumbnail',    'force_crop_woocommerce' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_shop_catalog',      'force_crop_woocommerce' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_shop_single',       'force_crop_woocommerce' );


function force_crop_woocommerce( $size ){
    $size['crop'] = 0;
    return $size;
}
```